# Is it possible to convert .xlwa file format to xsl using Apache poi?

Tags: java, apache-poi

We are using congos reports which returns output as .xlwa file.The requirement is to convert it into xls by reading the contents and write to a new xls file using the Apache POI.

Is it possible using the Apache poi?

Comment: .xlwa seems to be a special "Web Archive" format which is different than the normal .xlsx file format, Apache POI is currently not be able to read it.

If you can provide a sample file, developers can have a closer look.